# edge-triggered epoll and UDP's recvfrom()

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, epoll

I've been trying to learn edge-triggered `epoll` programming.  I'm confused about the little bit about how after `epoll_wait` one should loop over `recv` until it returns `EAGAIN` when it comes to UDP sockets -- does that mean I should loop over `recvfrom` until it returns `EAGAIN` as well?  If so, that means I will have to buffer UDP packets in case my application is trying to read fewer bytes than what was received.  But also, it's possible that if I loop `recvfrom`, I might get multiple packets from different sources -- I'd have to buffer the `sockaddr`s as well.  Is this true?

Comment: too many questions in one. Please simplify and structurize what you want

Comment: Note that recvfrom() for an UDP socket gives you exactly 1 (or 0 if the call fails) packet. If you don't provide room for the entire packet, the extra bytes are lost forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you should loop until `EAGAIN`=`EWOULDBLOCK` occurs. You MUST set O_NONBLOCK on this socket descriptor in order to acheive that.
2. You can not receive partial UDP packet.
3. You may return to event loop and receive from that socket next time when you want, but note that kernel may not wake up your `epol_wait` when packets received on socket, that was not end with `EAGAIN`.
4. While looping until EAGAIN, remember to in order to prevent `reader starvation`, you should save information that receiving on this FD is not complete when, say, 100 packets received. After that you should try another FD. When you decide to go back to event loop, just analyze saved information and try to receive unreceived packets.
5. I do not understand what you try to say about `sockaddr`.

Comment: for (4), i mean that if i loop on recvfrom, wouldn't it be possible to receive 2 packets from 2 different source addresses?  So if my application above is waiting to receive 1 packet, but by looping i get two packets from recvfrom, I'd have to buffer the second packet somehere until the application asks to receive another packet, right?

Comment: @atanamir yes, it is possible. use `recvfrom()`. You may process packet right after receiving, next receive second packet. Or, you can buffer all packets until some criteria. It's up to you how you will deisgn your program.